Why put a capacitor between VCC and a thermistor which is referenced to ground?
Just going through an old schematic here and noticed something strange:
there is a thermistor that is used to measure the board temperature, but it has a 0.1uF capacitor between VCC and the thermistor.
What purpose does this serve, and does it even work like this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: speff seems to have figured it out, which is extremely impressive considering the little information that I put into this post. The microcontroller used here is a Basic Stamp 2, which does not have any onboard ADCs, and instead uses a function called RCTIME to measure resistance and capacitance values. The actual code for this part of the circuit is:
The actual code used is:
GET_CASE_TEMP:                                     'used to read the case temperature
  HIGH CASE_TEMP_PIN                               'discharge capacitor
  PAUSE 1                                          'pause for 10 ms to discharge
  RCTIME CASE_TEMP_PIN, 1, CASE_TEMP               'get temp and in variable case_temp
  RETURN                                           'return to sender


Strange circuit. It should be a pull up resistor. Maybe it's just a mistake

Perhaps the 50k~100k internal pullup was calibrated to make a bridge voltage for the ADC but then the cap only adds 5V ripple to dither the input.

@D.A.S. I thought the same. And it could be referenced to Vcc, thus capacitor towards Vcc. Even if it were so, it is still weird and unusual.

For a microcontroller having no ADC, measuring exponential RC fall-time might yield an estimate of R12. You need an I/O pin that can be programmatically switched between output to input , and you need a timer. Showing the whole circuit might verify or support this conjecture.

Rt is 0V referenced and the cap may transfer supply ripple for a dual purpose if analyzed for Vmax-Vmin to detect strange effects on other analog I/O's .

Nice one glen but then logic threshold is temperature sensitive.

@D.A.S. If the circuit wasn't temperature sensitive it wouldn't be much good, would it? Also, the threshold, not so much.

Lots of room for improvement in old schematics. That's why "continuation or product support engineers" are so important.   FWIW @Spehro'speff'Pefhany

I would expect that the MCU puts the capacitor in a known state by driving P3 high- charging it through R13 (a relatively low resistance compared to 100kΩ), and then switches P3 to an input and measures the time required for the voltage at P3 to reach the fixed input threshold. The time will be proportional to the thermistor resistance.
This is a relatively crude method- a better one uses a relatively precise reference resistor (making two measurements) and the capacitor value cancels out. This method is used in almost all consumer thermometers (room temperature and medical) following a collaboration between one of the biggest thermistor makers in Japan and a major 4-bit MCU maker. Vdd cancels out as well, so it can be used with battery power and no regulation. It's almost an ideal method and deals well with both the wide dynamic range of room temperature measurements and the high precision demanded of medical thermometers (not necessarily both at the same time though). Dynamic range is brutal if you want a wide range: at -40°C a typical 10kΩ thermistor is about 336kΩ and at +125°C it is about 679Ω.

The risetime for logic levels has undocumented temperature sensitivity.  The mismatch of Pch/Nch Vt thresholds is likely undocumented but discrete IC's do have some plots which show both NTC and PTC characteristics of Vth = {Flat-Band V} + {2*Bulk Potential} + {Surface Depletion Potential} and all curves are affected by Vdd.  Thus calibration error correction is essential if one wants to reduce a wide temp range of est. 10% to 1% accuracy.  But for Room temp range it may be adequate.  What is the cost reduction to eliminate R and ADC in pennies? ;)

Rise time doesn't really enter into it - ns vs. ms  Threshold tempco is typically -0.04%/K NTC thermistor tempco is of the order of -5%/K. Capacitor tolerance is probably 5% at best. Absolute threshold is not well controlled. Circuit is likely good for 2 or 3°C without calibration. More than good enough for a high temperature cutoff.

Speff can you clarify how Rise time is not what you stated? "time required for the voltage at P3 to reach the fixed input threshold." Is there an assumed  precision Vref comparator or is it Vdd/2 +/- xx%

When using threshold to make a CMOS oscillator invert, my experience has been 5% threshold error affecting duty factor over industrial temp. range on some devices.  Do you recall where -0.04%/K comes from? I have seen it dip in the mid-range of temp, thus non-linear and NTC and PTC as I mentioned above.

@D.A.S. Deen, M. J. (1988). Cryogenic temperature dependence of the voltage transfer characteristics of CMOS inverters. Solid-State Electronics, 31(8), 1299–1308. doi:10.1016/0038-1101(88)90429-7 (average between 300K and 77K, it's fairly linear).

That report is based on twin-gate silicon-on-insulator (SOI) MOSFET. Are we to assume all uC inverter inputs will perform the same to 4.2'K with that tempco?

@D.A.S. In my experience 4.2K (liquid helium) is a totally different regime and strange things can happen to semiconductors (especially to bipolar parts and diodes), but 77K (LN2) to 400K is familiar territory and parts tend to behave similarly to room temperature and keep working if the circuit has reasonable margins (gm will drop, for example). Copper resistivity deviates from the ideal curve below 20-40K too, depending on purity.

I guess process designs have improved since my day. I only played with dry ice and tested an 8" Fujitsu hard disk drive packed in dry ice at the request of the US military. (-40) It started, ran and heads flew under the nominal microinch heights.  Of course CMOS loves to run faster at low temp with lower RdsOn.

Wow, this is absolutely what is happening. I managed to find the code that controls this part of the circuit, and you are right! The microcontroller here is a Basic Stamp 2, and one of the functions is something called RCTIME which is used to measure resistance or capacitance with a digital pin. Very interesting! I've never seen anything like this before.

it's a cheap way to prevent really fast oscillations driving the micro crazy.
It's not a low pass filter but it acts as one for really high on-off but short bursts  on the sensor side.
If the jitter is sharp enough and it holds long enough it will end up 'driving crazy' the micro, meaning, spoiling the measurement.
That capacitor blocks DC but allows AC through.
But for short burts it may just do the job, to let's say get a 'go ahead' in EMC certification and obtain FCC or/and EU approval to sell such product, without spending too much.
